# Make available a library created using browserify and browserify-shim

Tags: javascript, browserify, browserify-shim

I want to create a JavaScript library for browser using Browserify / Browserify Shim and make it available within the browser from a global variable.

I would want that the exports of the entry JS file would be attached on this variable. For example, in my library, I would have this:

```
exports.doSomething = function() {
    (...)
};
```

And, within my browser, I would like to do this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mylib.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#test').click(function() {
        mylib.doSomething();
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  (...)
</html>
```

How can I configure Browserify / Browserify Shim to achieve this?

Thanks very much for your help!
Thierry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot configure browserify to achieve this, because this is not how browserify works. But you can use browserify's `global` variable to publish your function.

Add the following line to your library:

```
global.doSomething = function() { ... }
```

Then change your html code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').click(function() {
    doSomething();
  });
});
```

NOTE: You don't have to include `mylib.js` separatly. Just include the bundle.

Be careful with your function/module names. The first code line will append the function to the `window`-object, so you could "pollute" the global space or more important: You could override an other global module.